# need to manually create symlinks every time i install something

Tags: bash

For example, I'm trying to install pipenv using the following commands:

```
$ pip3 install --user pipenv
$ cd ~/Documents/myproject
$ pipenv install requests
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

It seems that the issue can be resolved if I run `sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/pipenv /usr/bin`. Is this a safe thing to do? I've also been having this issue with several other packages, like `tensorboard` and `xflux`. Is there something wrong with my system that makes it such that I need to manually create a symlink every time? How can I change things so that packages can install normally without me having to do this every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the tools you are installing are being installed in non-standard locations and are not being included in your `PATH`. One way to resolve this would be to include the paths in your `PATH` environment variable. In order for these programs to be in your path every time you login, do this (assuming you are using `zsh` as your shell):

1) Open `~/.zshrc` using `vim` or any other editor:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

2) Append the following to this file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir/containing/pipenv
```

Remember to replace `/path/to/dir/containing/pipenv` with the appropriate path.

3) Source your `~/.zshrc` so that the path is included in your current session:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

4) Now everytime you login, the paths should be available in your environment and you won't need to create symlinks.